# How to use AutoExpireFlashBag in Symfony?

Tags: session, symfony

With my current configuration, inside a controller `$this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()` always returns a FlashBag instance.

I see in the documentation that there is an AutoExpireFlashBag class that automatically expires messages, whether consumed or not.

How do I get Symfony to use that class instead of the regular FlashBag class ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is set by a global parameter in config file. You need just rename class for flashbag in `session.flashbag.class` parameter. It is defined in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/session.xml#L9. But you can override it in your configs.

Comment: In Symfony 3 add `services:
    session.flash_bag:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\AutoExpireFlashBag` to your `sevices.yml`